# Where can I find a list indicating the vulnerability status of SOHO routers to Shellshock?

Tags: shellshock

I tried to Google this but information is very scant ATM. Is there anyone compiling a list with a specific focus on SOHO routers?

Comment: This question specifically asks for a reference source. The other question shares part of the subject area, but is more a "should I be worried" type of general reflexion which might be missed for people actually looking for detailed reference info like which routers/firmwares are verified not vulnerable, or where patches can be found.

Comment: This is a questions and answers site, not a link farm. We don't do lists of links. “How do I determine whether my router is vulnerable?” is the question we cater for instead. We can either close as a duplicate of a question that will help you, or as “Questions seeking product recommendations are off-topic as they become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.”.